# Can't boot from HDD after install of Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo V570

Tags: 14.04, boot, lenovo, pxe

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 as the only OS on Lenovo V750, I am unable to boot. I get messages:
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
PXE-M0F: Exiting  PXE ROM.

Boot order:
ATAPI CD
ATA HDD
PCI LAN

Tried installing a second time and still get same error.

Able to use Try Ubuntu from DVD which I used to do the install.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe assigning HDD as first boot device can help?

Comment: Yes, it is also possible the hard disk has croked. I had a Toshiba hard drive fail and got the same error. Since then, I adjust the hdparm settings to prevent unnecessary spin ups permanently setting `hdparm -B 254 /dev/sda*` in the /etc/hdparm.conf file by including:

`/dev/sda* {\
        apm_battery = 254\
        apm = 254\
}`

at the end of the file

Comment: Replaced hard drive and installed Ubuntu on hard drive again. Still won't boot from hard drive even what hard drive is first on boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced hard drive and installed again. Still was unable to boot. So put old hard drive back in and installed Red Hat Linux. That booted fine.